# Image not loading through ORM in SS4

Tags: silverstripe

I have a `ModularPage` class that extends `Page`. Page has a 'Thumbnail' `Image`.

I have an route for ajaxing a `ModularPage` collection. I grab the collection with the following:

```
$rootPage = DataObject::get_by_id('SilverStripe\\CMS\\Model\\SiteTree', $id);    
$pages = $rootPage->Children();

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    var_dump($page->Thumbnail()->Link()); // Null
    var_dump($page->ThumbnailID); // '4'
}
```

The ThumbnailID is populated but the thumbnail object is null. Is this a bug? Do I need to do anything different in SS4?

**Update:** So when I access the route directly from the browser the Link populates correctly. When accessing it through Ajax, `Link` is null.

**Update 2:** The image Link() also works as per normal when accessed from the same class, only when called through ajax does it get stripped.

Comment: Just out of curiosity if you get Is as the Real Page class does the magic method thumbnail() then return the corret entity. Eg get_by_id("Page" or how oit should be used with the namespacing. dont have a 4.0 build on the hand to test it just now.

Comment: On filtering Id also use the right class name to get the objects directly, if you acess a datafield thats not part of the primary query it will database requests per for each iteration. Page::get()->filter("parentId", whatever); should be more optimal than SiteTree::get as the latter would cause iteration to load new data for each of the items. That is if I have if I understood how it does it on atleast 3.2 correctly :)

Comment: @FinBoWa I tried calling the real `Page` class, still null when received from the endpoint. Good call on the efficiency of using `Page` over `SiteTree`, I will do that in future.

Comment: Curious (commenting on the updates). Have you tested a ss 3.x does it behave the same way? I'd suggest on using xdebug and stepping trough the code, but as for a quick fix you could use the thumbnailID to load up the relation manually, the magic method would do that anyways.

Comment: I haven't built it in 3.x yet. Was hoping I would find a solution before doing so. I think I need to though. I tried loading the image manually (DataObject::get_by_id) and got the same behaviour.

Comment: @FinBoWa I spun this up in SS3 and can confirm it is an SS4 bug.

Comment: that could be, thought its interesting that it only affects when its a ajax request? Could be a behavioral change on how the ajax request loads relations also. Unless there is any documentation on that > id suggest on firing up an issue on the framework

Comment: All over it ;) https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/6048

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damian helped sort this one out on the github issue: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/6048#issuecomment-248572357

There is an `$owns` static array that tells the parent object what relationships to publish when it is published.

Adding the following caused the Thumbnail to be published and is now displaying correctly:

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
    private static $owns = [
        'Thumbnail'
    ];
}
```

At the moment this looks like the only method for publishing assets. It looks the guys are discussing adding a publish button on assets in future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$page->Thumbnail()->Filename` to get the filename and build the img tag yourself. Or you can use one of the cropping methods such as `$page->Thumbnail()->resize(1024,768);`

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/files/image/

There isn't a `Link` method on `Image`.

Comment: `Image` inherits the `Link` function from the `File` class.